# Need ORACLE help returning second minimum date for one specific group else return earliest minimum date

Tags: date

I have current logic that is taking the minimum/earliest date for shipment/carrier for two different events.  However, for one carrier (lets say DEF), I need to return the date (for the bb_DT)  that is the second earliest (if there is one), otherwise return the minimum.  And i still need just the minimum for the other (aa_dt) field.

Here's simplified version of logic:

```
with statu as
(select s.shipment_id, s.carrier, 
case when event_cd = 'AA' then i.eventdate END AS "AA_DT",
case when event_cd = 'BB' then i.eventdate END AS "BB_DT"
from shipevent i 
join shipment s  on i.shipment_id=s.shipment_id
)
select statu.shipment_id, statu.carrier, 
min(statu.aa) as "MIN_AA",
min(statu.bb) as "MIN_BB"
from statu
group by statu.shipment_id, statu.carrier
```

If I have the following values in my statu table

| shipment ID | carrier | aa_dt | bb_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 1/1/2020 |  |
| 123 | ABC |  | 2/1/2020 |
| 123 | ABC |  | 3/1/2020 |
| 123 | ABC |  | 4/1/2020 |
| 456 | DEF | 3/1/2020 |  |
| 456 | DEF | 4/1/2020 |  |
| 456 | DEF |  | 3/15/2020 |
| 789 | GHI | 1/1/2020 |  |
| 789 | GHI |  | 1/15/2020 |
| 789 | GHI |  | 2/15/2020 |
| 001 | DEF | 2/2/2020 |  |
| 001 | DEF | 3/2/2020 |  |
| 001 | DEF |  | 2/18/2020 |
| 001 | DEF |  | 3/18/2020 |
| 001 | DEF |  | 3/30/2020 |
| 001 | DEF |  | 4/1/2020 |

I want to return

| shipment ID | carrier | aa_dt | bb_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 1/1/2020 | 2/1/2020 |
| 456 | DEF | 3/1/2020 | 3/15/2020 |
| 789 | GHI | 1/1/2020 | 1/15/2020 |
| 001 | DEF | 2/2/2020 | 3/18/2020 |

I tried playing around with using row_number and partitions but i just can't seem to get it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to figure out a solution. I added a field to `statu` that would have the `eventdate` for just my carrier. I forgot to originally show an additional field used, called the stop number, but it's part of the solution.

```
with statu as
(select s.shipment_id, s.carrier, 
case when event_cd = 'AA' then i.eventdate END AS "AA_DT",
case when event_cd = 'BB' then i.eventdate END AS "BB_DT",
case when s.carrier in ('DEF') and event_cd = 'BB' and 
row_number() over
  (Partition By s.shipment_id, s.stop_num, s.carrier, event_cd ORDER BY i.eventdate) = '2' then i.eventdate END as 'DEF_EVENT2_AB'
from shipevent i 
join shipment s  on i.shipment_id=s.shipment_id
)
select statu.shipment_id, statu.carrier, 
min(statu.aa) as "MIN_AA",
case when max(statu.def_event2_ab) is not null then max(statu.def_event2_ab) else min(statu.bb) as "BB"
from statu
group by statu.shipment_id, statu.carrier
```